# How to search words lists in a string with 'AND' and 'OR' operator?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to search pattern in some string/paragraph with operator and/or.

I tried many regex patterns but none of them helped me.

The some examples pattern that I want to search in strings/paragraphs is:

```
1. word1+word2+word3|word5|word6+word7
2. word1|word2+word3|word5
3. word1+word2|word3
```

'+' sign is represent for 'AND' operator so the word on left/right of it must be contain in string. '|' sign is represent 'OR' operator.

ps: this is not the only pattern. this pattern has multiple combination

So my question is how can I turn this pattern int some logical python3 code or some regex pattern?

Finally sorry for the grammar mistakes. English is not my native language. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide example strings that should be matched? Can you show what you tried?

Comment: For example, the pattern is "cat+dog|mouse" and example string that I want to search is:  ``` "This cat is beautiful, it will catch so many mouses." ``` this must be return false because according to pattern  string must contain 'cat' and 'dog' but 'mouse' word is not mandotary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that maybe you might want to design different expressions for each query, such as:

```
^(?=.*\bcats?\b)(?=.*\bmouses\b).*$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/wSkrjl/1/)

and you can use alternation, if you wish to join multiple expressions:

```
^(?=.*\bcats?\b)(?=.*\bmouses\b).*$|^(?=.*\bdogs?\b)(?=.*\bcats?\b).*$
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/cyk9bc/1/)

This method is pretty inefficient, for if there was no other choices.

Comment: Define alternation in practice. Please expound

Comment: @Emma Thank you for your help. This pattern worked.